# How to get list of object(equipement) for each object (intervention) manytomany relationship in django

Tags: django, model, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

models equipement :

```
    class Equipement(models.Model):
        nom_equipement=models.CharField(max_length=60)
        qte_stock=models.IntegerField()
        panne=models.ManyToManyField(Panne)
```

models intervention :

```
    class Intervention(models.Model):
        Titre_intervention = models.TextField(max_length=255)
        date_intervention = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        type_panne = models.ForeignKey(Panne,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        etat = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        description = models.TextField(max_length=255)
        image = models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,upload_to='medial/%Y/%m/%D')
        equipements = models.ManyToManyField(Equipement)
        clients = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
```

models intervention with relationship manytomany :

so when I add a new "intervention" it will add to table of association

[image]

I need to list all equipment of each intervention this is my view :

```
    def mes_intervention(request):
            if 'id_client' in request.session:
                get_idClient=request.session['id_client']
                Interv_client = Intervention.objects.all().filter(clients=get_idClient)

                context = {
                    'intervention':Interv_client
                    }

                return render(request, 'clients/mes-intervention.html',context)
```

and this is where I list all intervention into template html

[image]

Comment: which part of code is not helpful ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a side note, you have plurals and singulars a bit mixed up. A foreign key points to **one** model:

- `client = models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True) # singular`

A queryset returns multiple objects:

- `context = { 'interventions': Interv_client}`

While you cannot call functions in templates with arguments, you can invoke object methods without arguments. So, you can in fact do this:

```
{% for item in interventions %}
   ...
   {% for equipment in item.equipements.all %}
       {{ equipment.qte_stock }}
   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot It Help , please can you suggest a tuto to learn complex query ?

Comment: There is a lot linked here: https://www.fullstackpython.com/django-orm.html